# cordova/ionic app crashes after startup on older versions of android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

The app runs fine on ios and `android 4.4+` and `lollipop`. However on older android versions (e.g 4.1.1) the app crashes directly after I start it.

Full stacktrace her is the logcat stack trace on such a tablet (Not sure which piece I had to copy) [here the link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZMChq7latXYl3czjwuhoW4ZfCukWefpH2nwScQ6_HGk/)

The exception is rather vague.

Thank you!

Comment: Ctrl+F for cordova and you see which part matters and can paste in a code box here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android 4.4+ use chromium as default browser, while any version below use android-browser.
It is much weaker browser. If your app runs perfectly in ios or android-4.4, then this could be the reason.

one work around is to use crosswalk by intel. cordova-crosswalk. [Read More](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html).

Basically it wraps your app in chromium browser, and package it as android app.
when the app run, it run chromium first( instead of android-browser) and then the code inside of it. 
noticable cons is extra 15-20mb to your app filesize.

- to migrate from cordova to crosswalk cordova. [read More](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html).

In the recent update, it seems there is new command to migrate app automatically. 
But what i did previously, was to do manual migration (by copy paste).

```
> few Tips if you do manually:
> 1. create new crosswalk project from cli
> 2. copy files in **www folder in cordova** to **www folder in crosswalk**
>        EXCLUDING one file : config.xml

> 3. Install your plugin manually. Read More: http://goo.gl/wF4CmD.
> 4. in crosswalk,set the config.xml manually.
```